# Why `constexpr const int &a = 1;` failed in block scope?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

N4527 7.1.5[dcl.constexpr]p9

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized. If it is initialized by a constructor call, that call shall be a constant
>   expression (5.20). **Otherwise, or if a constexpr specifier is used in a reference declaration, every full-expression that appears in its initializer shall be a constant expression.**

5.20[expr.const]p5

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression whose value refers to an entity that is a
>   permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose
>   value is an object where, for that object and its subobjects:
>
> — each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression, and
>
> — if the object or subobject is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such an object (5.7), the address of a function, or a null pointer value.
>
> An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or it is a
>   function.

```
void foo(){
    constexpr const int &a = 1;//error
    constexpr static const int &b = 1;//ok in gcc 5.1.0 and clang 3.8.0

}
```

Question: Why `constexpr const int &a = 1;` failed in block scope?

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour `N4140` has no **5.20**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in [cwg defect report 2005: Incorrect constexpr reference initialization requirements](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#2005) which says (*emphasis mine*):

> Consider an example like:
>
> ```
>   constexpr int f() { return 5; } // function must be constexpr
>   constexpr int && q = f();       // but result is not constant
>   constexpr int const & r = 2;    // temporary is still not constant
>   int main() {
>     q = 11;                       // OK
>     const_cast< int & >( r ) = 3; // OK (temporary object is not ROMable)
>
>     constexpr int && z = 7;       // Error? Temporary does not have static storage duration?
>   }
> ```
>
> A constexpr reference must be initialized by a constant expression
>   (7.1.5 [dcl.constexpr] paragraph 9), yet it may refer to a modifiable
>   temporary object. Such a temporary is guaranteed static
>   initialization, but it's not ROMable.
>
> A non-const constexpr reference initialized with an lvalue expression
>   is useful, because it indicates that the underlying storage of the
>   reference may be statically initialized, or that no underlying storage
>   is required at all.
>
> When the initializer is a temporary, finding its address is trivial.
>   There is no reason to declare any intent the computation of its
>   address. On the other hand, an initial value is provided, and that is
>   also required to be a constant expression, although it's never treated
>   as a constant.
>
> The situation is worse for local constexpr references. The initializer
>   generates a temporary when the declaration is executed. The temporary
>   is a locally scoped, unique object. This renders constexpr
>   meaningless, because although the address computation is trivial, it
>   still must be done dynamically.
>
> C++11 constexpr references required initialization by reference
>   constant expressions, which had to “designate an object with static
>   storage duration or a function” (C++11 5.20 [expr.const] paragraph 3).
>   A temporary with automatic storage duration granted by the reference
>   fails this requirement.
>
> C++14 removes reference constant expressions and the static storage
>   requirement, rendering the program well-defined with an apparently
>   defeated constexpr specifier. (GCC and Clang currently provide the
>   C++11 diagnosis.)
>
> Suggested resolution: **a temporary bound to a constexpr reference
>   should itself be constexpr, implying const-qualified type. Forbid
>   binding a constexpr reference to a temporary unless both have static
>   storage duration. (In local scope, the static specifier fixes the
>   issue nicely.)**

The response is that this is already forbidden by `5.20` paragraph 4:

> This issue is already covered by 5.20 [expr.const] paragraph 4, which includes conversions and temporaries in the analysis.

Comment: I don't understand why **5.20 [expr.const] p4** forbids this. There's no implicitly conversions here.

Comment: @stackcpp as far as I can tell the sentence that applies in this case would be `where the reference binding (if any) binds directly`

Comment: **its initializer shall be a constant expression**, and 5.20 [expr.const] p4 is **converted constant expression**, why p4 applies here?

Comment: @dyp that is originally what I thought but they use `5.20` which was the numbering after that paragraph moved, or at least as far as I can tell it is.

Comment: Well, the quote says "which includes conversions and temporaries" which I think p5 does not talk about or include (therefore I've removed my earlier comment). The reference binding in p4 is quite confusing, I don't quite understand what it's referring to (oops, pun not intended). If it does indeed refer to the initialization of a `constexpr T&` reference variable, why does the whole paragraph talk about converted constant expressions? But otherwise, it seems to fit in.

Comment: @dyp agreed, not sure, I was trying to piece it together but it is not obvious. The bulletted version of paragraph `4` seems to have come from here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html back when it was still paragraph `3` and it included `A reference constant expression is an lvalue
core constant expression that designates an object with static storage duration or a function` ... so it would seem they believed it covered that case then.

Comment: *"A reference constant expression is an lvalue ..."* Oh yes, that's why I was so confused. I need to get C++11 separated from C++14 in my head. However, in drafts just prior to nov 2014 (which is the date of the remark you've quoted in the last paragraph of your answer), p4 refer to the same as it does today: *"A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expressio"*

Comment: @dyp yes, so in C++11 p3 contained `A reference constant expression is an lvalue core constant expression that designates an object with static storage duration or a function` and then it was changed to a bullet list and is now p4 and so p4 should still cover the same cases which is what is implied by the defect report.